# undefined reference to 'void format<>(char const*)'

Tags: c++, linux, шаблоны-с++, gcc

corelib/fmt.hpp

```
__attribute__((__visibility("default"))) std::string format(std::string _fmt,
                               Args... args);
```

corelib/fmt.cpp

```
static std::string _format(std::string _fmt,
                           std::string _out) {
  // TODO: Formatting
}

template <class T>
static std::string _format(std::string _fmt,
                           std::string _out,
                           T arg) {
  // TODO: Formatting
}

template <class T, class... Args>
static std::string _format(std::string _fmt,
                           std::string _out,
                           T arg,
                           Args... args) {
  // TODO: Formatting
}

template <class... Args>
std::string format(std::string _fmt,
                   Args... args) {
  return _format(_fmt, "", args...);
}
```

corelib/CMakeLists.txt

```
# Entry point
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
add_library(fagrcore SHARED)

# Source/Private headers
add_subdirectory(src)

# Public headers
target_include_directories(fagrcore PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

corelib/src/CMakeLists.txt

```
target_sources(fagrcore PRIVATE fmt.cpp)
```

prog/main.cpp

```
#include <core/fmt.hpp>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  std::cout << core::format("THAT'S WORKING\n");
}
```

prog/CMakeLists.txt

```
# Entry point
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
add_executable(prog)

# Source
add_subdirectory(src)

# Dependencies
target_link_libraries(prog PRIVATE corelib)
```

**Без создания библиотеки (т.е просто добавив к prog исходники corelib) весь код работает на ура.**

#### Полная ошибка

здесь немного другие пространства имен, и название функций.
Например `println` просто вызывает `format` и `std::cout`

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/fagreditor.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to `void fagr::core::println<>(char const*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [editor/CMakeFiles/fagreditor.dir/build.make:100: ../bin/fagreditor] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:414: editor/CMakeFiles/fagreditor.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

Comment: А если `target_link_libraries(prog PUBLIC corelib)` ?

Comment: Ладно. Я нашел решение, нужно просто вывести реализацию функций в загаловочный файл или в файле .cpp реализовать все выриации шаблонов, что в моем случае как я понял невозможно. Знает ли кто-то другой вариант решения, т.е чтобы оставить реализацию всех функций в .cpp файле?

Comment: @Sheridan Нет это не помогло

Comment: ааа, ну да, это ж шаблоны... Почитайте там: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file

Comment: *"здесь немного другие пространства имен, и название функций."* - приводите настояший код и настоящее сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: @user7860670 https://github.com/klementievdmitry/fagr-engine. engine/fagrcore. Проблема исправлена вынесением реализации в заголовочный файл, как я понял в моем случае это единственное правильное решение.

Comment: Вообще еще есть `std::format`, не факт, что велосипедостроение тут себя оправдает.

Comment: @user7860670 Спасибо, не знал что в стандартной билблиотеке предусмотренно форматирование, а загуглить не догадался =)

Answer (score 0):

## Как я понял, единственное решение проблемы - вынести реализацию в заголовочный файл.

Как отметил @user7860607 в комментариях к вопросу есть [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format), странно что никто не отметил библиотеку [`fmt`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt). Но здесь как раз таки суть в велосипедостроении, я принципиально не использовал два этих решения.